# Push notifications with Phonegap and Pushwoosh when app is not started

Tags: cordova, push-notification, pushwoosh

I've created an app using Phonegap Build (3.1.0) and Pushwoosh. Everything works fine when the app is in the foreground or background.

What doesn't happen is that when the app is completely stopped the notifications don't reach it. Is there anything I can do (using Phonegap) to allow the device to receive push notifications without the app running?

Comment: What device is it? Android?  What version?  And how do you stop the app?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when the application is on background or closed, the OS itself handles the notification. Please note that you can send custom data with the notification on our Premium account (Additional data -> Custom data in the Control Panel).